# How to convert wstring to LPOLESTR?

Tags: wstring

The below is the one that I have tried and it did not work.

```
std::wstring = L"Text";
USES_CONVERSION;
LPOLESTR lpDesc = W2OLE((LPWSTR)wsDescr.c_str());
```

Please any one cany say what is the better way to do?

Comment: Just noticed, but std::wstring = L"Text"; is not valid. Where is the variable name?

Answer (score 8):

`LPOLESTR` is a string of `OLECHAR` which is essentially `wchar_t`. So `LPOLESTR` is a null-terminated `wchar_t*`. `LPOLESTR` is a `typedef` created by Microsoft. These are vestiges of an automatic ANSI / Unicode conversion scheme that Microsoft used prior to MFC 4.0 and has since abandoned. For Win32 development, "OLE" corresponds to Unicode. For example, in Win32 development, an `OLECHAR` is simply a `wchar_t` and an `LPOLESTR` is a wide character string (e.g. `wchar_t*`).

To construct `wstring` from an array of `wchar_t` characters it is straight forward -

```
wchar_t* Array = L"Hello";
std::wstring strArray(Array);
```

to convert the other direction from wstring to wchar_t*, you can do this -

```
wstring wstr = L"Test wstring";
const wchar_t *pwstr = wstr.c_str();
```

you can also try this,

```
LPOLESTR tempString = W2OLE((wchar_t*)wstring_temp.c_str());
```

Comment: LPOLESTR is a `wchar_t *`, not a `const wchar_t *`, so doing `pwstr = wstr.c_str()` is illegal without a cast, but then that raises some uncomfortable question: if it's not const, then is it safe to do it?

Comment: @user195488 where does `wstring_temp` come from ?

Answer (score 1):

You need no conversion at all, just copy the string:

```
std::wstring str = L"Text";
LPOLESTR lpDesc = (LPOLESTR) new wchar_t[str.length() + 1];
strcpy(lpDesc, str.c_str());
delete[] lpDesc;
```

Comment: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to 'LPOLESTR'

Comment: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to 'LPOLESTR'...I am getting this error while doing so

Comment: @Jörgen Sigvardsson: I have no clue what you meant with that.

Comment: @nightcracker: He's saying that you don't construct `char *c = new char*[10];` you construct it with `char *c = new char[10];` so if you breakdown `LPOLESTR` it actually is just a `typedef` of `wchar_t*`